# Place Event into Windows Event Log from Oracle

Tags: windows, oracle

I'm trying to place an event into the Windows event log from Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER.

(I'm open to other methods, just from what I've read it looks like DBMS_SCHEDULER is the best option to do this.)

I did a fair amount of research and this seems to be the basic structure for running Windows commands in Oracle:

```
BEGIN
sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job( 
   job_name            => 'TESTJOB',
   job_type            => 'EXECUTABLE',
   job_action          => 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe',
   job_class           => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
   number_of_arguments => 3,
   auto_drop           => FALSE,
   enabled             => FALSE);
sys.dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('TESTJOB', 1, '/q'); 
sys.dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('TESTJOB', 2, '/c');
sys.dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('TESTJOB', 3, '<desired command>');
sys.dbms_scheduler.enable('TESTJOB');
END;
```

I tried substituting `<desired command>` with:

```
eventcreate /L Application /SO MyMessage /T Warning /id 218 /D "testing 123"
```

However this resulted in the following error when I try to run the job:

```
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: Incorrect function.
```

I then changed `<desired command>` to this just out of curiosity if it would work with other commands:

```
dir>testFile.txt
```

And a `testFile.txt` was created... so it seems that Oracle allows some commands but not others. Why? Is there a way around this?

I also tried a few other things, such as putting the `eventcreate` statement into a batch file and then running the batch file from Oracle, still same error.

I should mention, running the full "job action" command and arguments with `eventcreate` directly from the command line produces the desired result.

At this point I'm pretty much ready to throw in the towel and just write a basic application with C# or something similar which places an entry into the Windows event log and run the executable directly from Oracle without dealing with these Windows commands.

(**EDIT**: After posting the question, I actually did do this, but now I'm running into other issues. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169480/place-event-into-windows-event-log-with-oracle).)

Am I missing something?

P.S. Even the `dir>testFile.txt` command that works takes roughly 1 or 2 seconds to run. This is strange to take such a long time to run such a basic command. It makes me think something is fundamentally wrong here.