# Place Event into Windows Event Log with Oracle

Tags: windows, oracle

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156436/place-event-into-windows-event-log-from-oracle).

I was having trouble with Oracle performing the `eventcreate` Windows command from `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

As a workaround, I instead created a basic C# application to perform the same `eventcreate` function. It works on a basic level but I'm facing a few roadblocks.

Here is the program. (I'm not tagging C# in this question because the question is not about C#. I am just providing this as information only.)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class myEventCreateClass
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {   
        using(EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
        {
            eventLog.Source = "MySource";
            eventLog.WriteEntry(args[0], EventLogEntryType.Warning, 218);
        }
    }
}
```

I modified the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` job to this:

```
BEGIN
sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job( 
   job_name            => 'SYS.TESTJOB',
   job_type            => 'EXECUTABLE',
   job_action          => 'C:\myEventCreate.exe',
   job_class           => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
   number_of_arguments => 1,
   auto_drop           => FALSE,
   enabled             => FALSE);
sys.dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('SYS.TESTJOB', 1, 'testing123');
sys.dbms_scheduler.enable('SYS.TESTJOB');
END;
```

When I run this job manually under the `SYS` schema, it successfully places an event into the Windows event log that says:

```
testing123
```

This is where my success ends...

---

If I create the same job under a different schema (e.g. change all instances of `SYS.TESTJOB` to `MYSCHEMA.TESTJOB`), it creates the job in that schema but when I attmept to run the job (from any schema) I get the following long list of errors:

```
ORA-27370: job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:accessing job scheduler service failed with status: 2
ORA-27301: OS failure message: The system cannot find the file specified.
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sjsec 6a
ORA-27303: additional information: The system cannot find the file specified.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 185
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 486
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

And when I try to run `SYS.TESTJOB` from `MYSCHEMA`, it tells me the job doesn't exist:

```
ORA-27476: "SYS.TESTJOB" does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 185
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 486
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How can I get this job working from a schema other than `SYS`?

---

One more problem (probably the bigger issue): I am trying to run this job from inside a trigger.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375946/can-a-job-be-created-dynamically-inside-a-trigger), changing the settings of a `DBMS_SCHEDULER` job (in my case, I'm attempting to change the job arguments each time before I run the job) causes an implicit `COMMIT` in Oracle, which is not allowed in triggers.

To me it seems misleading for Oracle to even label these as "arguments", because the values of the arguments are fixed inside the job, and changing the arguments means changing the job itself.

Anyway, the accepted answer in this question says to use `DBMS_JOB` since this does not implicitly `COMMIT`, but I can't find a way to use `DBMS_JOB` to run an external `.exe` file.

Therefore, is it possible to modify this job somehow to allow dynamic job arguments?

---

I'm also open to other solutions, but from what I have read, `DBMS_SCHEDULER` seems to be the best way to accomplish this.

---

As requested, here is some context for what I am trying to accomplish:

At my company, we have it set up such that if an entry is placed into the Windows event log under a certain source (e.g. in this case, `mySource` as shown in the provided C# application), a text message containing the content of the user log message is automatically sent the cell phones of myself and a few other admins.

This is extremely useful as it gives us an immediate notification that some event of importance happened, and we can control exactly which events we want to include and what specific information about these events we want to be notified of.

Here are some examples of what we currently get notified about via text message:

1. The stopping or starting of any of our custom applications (and who stopped/started it if it didn't crash).
2. When any of our custom applications are taken into or out of watchdog control (and who did this).
3. When certain "known issues" arise or are about to arise that we haven't fully fixed yet. This allows us to get "ahead of the game" so that we can deal with it proactively rather than waiting for someone to tell us about it.

I want to extend this functionality to some events in our Oracle database (which is why I am trying to place an event into the event log based on a trigger in Oracle).

Here are some things I have in mind as of now that we want to be notified of via text message, all of which can be determined inside a trigger:

1. When anyone not in a certain "approved" list of users (which would be our admins plus the custom applications with connections to Oracle) connects to our Oracle database. This can be accomplished with a logon trigger. (Actually, I already have this one working since the logon triggers are called by the `SYS` schema, so I'm not having issues with other schemas not being able to run the job. But... since I still can't change any arguments, the best I can currently do is just say `"Someone" not approved logged into Oracle database...`. It would be alot more useful if I could pass the username to the Windows event log.)
2. When anything besides our custom applications changes data in our Oracle database. (Our custom applications handle all of the inserts/updates/deletes etc. Only in very rare cases would we need to manually modify something. We want to be notified when ***anyone*** [including myself or other admins] modifies anything the database.) This can be accomplished with an update/insert/delete trigger for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is working under *SYS* is that it is special privileged account.  You need to create a new credential and map it to the job

The solution would be create a credential with [DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_CREDENTIAL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_credential.htm#CIHBFACD) together with OS account that has enough privileges and assign this new credential to your job.

For the trigger issue to be honest I don't know yet.

### **Edit** - solution based using Oracle's subtransaction facility

After OP update and reaction to comments:

Based on the workflow I think it is better to use internal Oracle's notification to do the *responsive* audit. I think trying to hack yourself f into Windows event log via external application is bringing another unnecessary layer of complexity.

I would create a table within DB where I would store all the events and on top of that table I would create a Job with notifications (SMS, mail, etc) which would be run if any change to the log table occurs.

In order to use triggers when an error occurs you should use [`PRAGMA autonomous_transaction`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm) from your main scope (allows you to do a subtransaction). This will allow you to commit any `DML` you may have, but do a rollback the rest.

Comment: Should this credential be created to `SYS.TESTJOB` or `MYSCHEMA.TESTJOB`?

Comment: It should be created for `MYSCHEMA`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry I can't award the bounty yet since this only partially addresses the issue. I will try to create the credential when I get back to work on Monday.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 don't worry,  I understand. For full fledged solution it would help to understand a bigger picture: what exactly are you trying to achieve? (Complete workflow)

Comment: Good idea, see the revised question, I have added an explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 From the sound of it what you are trying to do is a auditing of the database.  Why aren't you using the std. tools available is there any reason for that?

Comment: Yes we already use some of these such as looking at the `DBA_AUDIT_SESSION` table to see a record of who connected or disconnected. But the idea with this question is to get an _immediate_ notification of certain actions, and we get this immediate notification if an event is placed into the Windows event log.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 I see.  I personally would not try to hack myself into Windows event log via eternal application.  I would create a table within DB where I would store all the events and  on top of that table I would create a Job with notifications (SMS, mail, etc) which would be run if any change to the log table occurs.

Comment: Yes that is an option I considered but I'm against that for this reason: Sometimes in the triggers I want to raise an error, and I've found through testing that if an error is raised, any `INSERT` statements that happened previously in the trigger were rolled back. So in these cases I wouldn't get the indication that I want. This is why using an external application is useful, because it will always be called even if an error is raised.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889  I think you should look at the `PRAGMA autonomous_transaction` (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm) from your main scope.  It may be a solution for the roll back trigger(s).  If an error is raised you could still commit a subtransaction.

Comment: Yea, I just realized that after I typed this comment haha, I'll try to commit these `INSERT`s that would normally be rolled back otherwise with this `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`.

Comment: `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` is working for this purpose. I feel bad rewarding the bounty to the other answer because that was just the last piece of the puzzle, but you provided valuable information more abundantly. Can you modify your answer expanding on some of these ideas (e.g. instead of writing to the event log with external application, write to a table inside Oracle directly, and then deal with job notifications later.) Then the bounty can be awarded.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 glad to hear that.  I know it is hard to ask questions, because it can be rather complex.  I'll edit the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

the permissions problem is already resolved in the other answer. For the 'commit inside a trigger' problem, there is the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`. See bottom of this link for an example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm. It does exactly what you want.